# Rails - one form, validation in two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, validation

I have a form for the registration of new users. In the form are these inputs:

- name (model_a)
- age (model_a)
- email (model_a)
- icq (model_b)
- skype (model_b)

All fields are required.
The first 3 fields are in **model_a** and the last two in **model_b**. In both models I have already prepared validation rules.

It should work this way: User make registration and into the table **model_a** will be saved first 3 fields, into the table **model_b** last two fields.

But how to set up the form this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at *Nested forms*

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1